# How can i open a notepad file (or any process) using webservice deployed in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis-7

How can i open notepad file from another computer using webservice ?

Locally the webservice is running fine and when invoke it opens the notepad file,but when the webservice is deployed in server the notepad file does not get opened.

Code :

```
 //Process
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public void notepadopen()
  {

   Process.Start("F:\\log.txt");
  }
```

**Note** : Also tried

```
Process.Start(@"\\192.168.1.8\f\log.txt");
```

I have already done several methods , some reference SO posts :

[Need to execute *.exe in server from ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658555/need-to-execute-exe-in-server-from-asp-net)

**Tried setting load user profile to true**
[image]

[Invoke an application using webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358947/invoke-an-application-using-webservice)

[Foo.cmd won't output lines in process (on website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575386/foo-cmd-wont-output-lines-in-process-on-website)

**Already gave permission to access the folder and file**
[image]

**Also Enabled ASP impersonation**
[image]

**ISAPI and CGI restriction :**
[image]

**Application pool pipeline :**

[image]

> How can i open a notepad file (or any process) remotely using
>   webservice ?
>
> i can run above program in ASP development server , but cannot run the
>   same when deployed in IIS

If you are unclear or have found any post related please post them.

Any help would be of great use.Thanks

Comment: have you tried calling notepad with the file as a parameter? Process.Start("notepad.exe F:\\log.txt");

Comment: your command will show error..have a try

Comment: Map F: drive on remote machine and give the qualified path with mapped drive name and then txt file..

Comment: no result after doing same @RajKarri

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to achieve here. If, ultimately, you succeed in running another program, it will be running *on the server* and it will not be visible/usable for any user who happens to be logged on to the server (via e.g. Remote Desktop). Is that really what you're aiming for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i can run above program in ASP development server , but cannot run the same when deployed in IIS..

Comment: When you use the ASP development server, it's running as *you*, interactively, rather than as a service. Also, your machine is acting in both the roles of a *client* (because you're using a browser) *and* as a server (because you're running the server). That's a *very* different environment to when running under IIS.

Comment: thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever for your time..is there anything to try the same so that i can get the result ?